# RestClientException Could not extract response spring mvc

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, dispatcher

i'm trying to connect via the restTemplate to the server side in order to retrieve xml's. But i'm taking an RestClientException and this message:"Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [frontend.model.Registration] and content type [application/xml]"
In the dispatcher-servlet i write this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
 <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
        <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
        <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
    </map>
 </property>
 <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
    </list>
 </property>
```

And afterwards i add this:

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
```

Also the exception appears at this line:3

```
 ResponseEntity<Registration> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://www.../ckp/user/{id}",
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, Registration.class, id);
```

I can't solve the problem days now..i'm thinking to add ViewResoler and MessageConverter by i don't know which resolvers and which converters. Can anyone propose something to try? 
Should i add something on disptcher servlet?should i add a library?
My model classes are pojo's contains jaxb annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the xml message converter bean to the `RestTemplate` bean definition. This is what I use:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Don't forget to inject the `restTemplate` bean into your class (via xml or annotation).

EDIT: In your class where you call RestTemplate, add a field like this:

```
@Inject
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!what you mean to inject the class?Sorry i'm newbie. Moreover i need to add a new library to support this?

Comment: Could you give me an example?And one more question, only the :<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/> i need for the application/xml.Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you only need that converter if you are only interested in consuming XML web services. See edits in answer. You may want to use @Autowired annotation (Spring equivalent of javax.inject.Inject).

Comment: Thank you for your help.i try this but it doesn't work.I try with the @Autowired annotation because hitting me an error when i use the Inject annotation. And i'm taking again the same exception

Comment: What is the error? As both annotations give you the error, it suggests there is another issue causing this... Try Googling for the specific exception thrown.